# Plotting lambda function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, lambda

I am trying to plot a function which is defined via a `lambda`. I always get the error message:

```
x and y must have the same first dimension but have shapes (20,) and (1,)
```

But I have no idea why.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-4,8,20)
print(x)
fx = lambda x: x - 10 * np.exp(-1/10*((x-2)**2)) 
plt.plot(x, fx)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fx` is a `lambda` function, `x` is a list.
You shall first compute all the results and then pass it to the plot:

```
x  = np.linspace(-4,8,20)
fx = lambda x: x - 10 * np.exp(-1/10*((x-2)**2)) 
y  = [fx(val) for val in x] # Not sure, maybe you need to use Numpy too instead ? Not a expert of Numpy

plt.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: `plt.plot(x, fx(x))` is enough

Comment: @diggusbickus As the lambda function is waiting for a number and not a list, i'm not sure this will do the trick ? ```x = [1, 2, 3, 4]; fx = lambda x: x+1; y = fx(x) >>TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list```

Comment: it an `np.array` not `list`

Comment: As said above, not an expert in Numpy (at all). Then passing a np array when a number is intended works ? Wow.

Comment: yes numpy is that wow!